# Codekit not showing bower components

Tags: bower, codekit

Just got latest paid version of codekit 2.0.4 for osx 10.8.2

Just watched all videos including creating new projects with bower.

Ask a question tab on help page of codekit site does nothing, so don't know where else to ask this.

I have bower, compass, sass, git installed via command line.

When I drop new folder into codekit, and go to assets, nothing shows up.  Nothing in favorites, and nothing under components.  Search does nothing, so I assume it's only searching items shown.  I guess codekit isn't connecting somehow, but I don't see anything else to set up.

thx.

edit:  Answered via email.  If anyone has similar issue, check network connection settings first.  In my case, it was Little Snitch.  I just didn't realize it because I never got the pop-up telling me Codekit was attempting to dial out.

Anyway, dev was helpful, it's resolved, and Codekit works just fine.

Thx, Bryan.

Answer (score 0):

For others who see this behavior but may not be running Little Snitch/etc. I use a VPN client called Viscosity. Even though I was not running an active VPN tunnel, I needed to quit Viscosity before Codekit would download the active list of Bower components.

Answer (score 0):

I just got bit by this one as well. Had to quit Viscosity and also open Activity Monitor and kill the Viscosity Helper process as well and then everything loaded fine. Ergh.